# Drupal menu management seems lacking compared to WordPress: Am I missing anything?

Tags: 7, routes

I'm trying to understand how to best add content links to menus. As far as I can tell, there are two limited ways:

1. In the content edit screen, click the "Provide a menu link" checkbox. **Shortcoming:** This will only add links to the main menu- you can't target other menus from the content edit interface?
2. In the menu edit screens, you can add links. **Shortcoming:**  You have to spell out the paths. Seems like it would be a lot easier if there was a content finder on this screen so that you could easily select the content, a la WordPress and every other CMS.

I'm coming from WordPress, which has a basic but robust menu management system. Is Drupal just lagging in this regard? Are there better ways of handling menu links?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. On node edit page, upon checking "Provide a menu link" populates a select box with menus and theirs items which are associated with this content type. To include other menus you need to edit your content type.
2. You are right in this regard but there can be some module.

Comment: You're catching everything I throw at ya ;)  thanks-